# T-SQL Creating Dynamic Tables and Populating

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Im fairly new to T-SQL and could use some help with a Script I am writing. The purpose of the script is to create dynamic tables and populate them with related data. Currently Im getting a vague error which Im guessing is caused because Im missing some syntax. The script is below. The idea is that I will run the script one time to create and load these tables. This process is part of a data migration project. Here's the error Im receiving when I "Execute" the script. Any tips or suggestions are appreciated. Thanks ahead of time.

ERROR

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 81
Incorrect syntax near 'getSFContactID'.
```

SCRIPT

```
USE mylocalDB;
GO
-- Declare variables to temporarily hold dynamic SQL scripts
DECLARE @V_SF_CONTACT_ID VARCHAR(18) = '', 
        @V_TABLESCRIPT NVARCHAR(MAX) = '',
        @V_INSERTSCRIPT NVARCHAR(MAX) = '',
-- Declare variables to temporarily hold query records
        @V_FIRST_NAME nvarchar(50) = '',
        @V_LAST_NAME nvarchar(50) = '',
        @V_COMPANY nvarchar(100) = '',
        @V_ADDRESS_1 nvarchar(50) = '',
        @V_ADDRESS_2 nvarchar(50) = '',
        @V_CITY nvarchar(50) = '',
        @V_STATE nvarchar(2) = '',
        @V_ZIP nvarchar(10) = '',
        @V_Phone nvarchar(20) = ''


DECLARE getSFContactID CURSOR
FOR SELECT distinct CONTACTSFID FROM xrefListContactToAccountKey


OPEN getSFContactID


FETCH NEXT FROM getSFContactID
INTO @V_SF_CONTACT_ID


WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

/******************************************************
        BEGIN CREATING DYNAMIC TABLES
*******************************************************/

SET @V_TABLESCRIPT = '';
SET @V_INSERTSCRIPT = '';

IF OBJECT_ID(@V_SF_CONTACT_ID, 'U') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN

    SET @V_TABLESCRIPT = 'CREATE TABLE [dbo].[' + @V_SF_CONTACT_ID + '](
        [Key] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT FOR REPLICATION NOT NULL,
        [FIRST_NAME] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
        [LAST_NAME] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
        [COMPANY] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
        [ADDRESS_1] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
        [ADDRESS_2] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
        [CITY] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
        [STATE] [nvarchar](2) NOT NULL,
        [ZIP] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
        [Phone] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
     CONSTRAINT [PK_' + @V_SF_CONTACT_ID + '] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED ([Key] ASC )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]) ON [PRIMARY]';
    --PRINT @V_SF_CONTACT_ID
    EXEC (@V_TABLESCRIPT)

    BREAK

    SET @V_INSERTSCRIPT = 'INSERT INTO [dbo].[' + @V_SF_CONTACT_ID + ']
        Select      CL.FirstName as FIRST_NAME,
                    CL.LastName as LAST_NAME,
                    CL.COMPANY,
                    CL.Street as ADDRESS_1,
                    CL.Street2 as ADDRESS_2,
                    CL.CITY,
                    CL.[STATE],
                    CL.ZIP,
                    CL.Phone
                FROM    [dbo].[Contact] CL

                WHERE CONTACTSFID = ''' + @V_SF_CONTACT_ID + '';

    EXEC (@V_INSERTSCRIPT)

FETCH NEXT FROM getSFContactID INTO @V_SF_CONTACT_ID

END


CLOSE getSFContactID
DEALLOCATE getSFContactID
```

Comment: remove the `BREAK` and try this code again.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Same error just one line up..Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 80
Incorrect syntax near 'getSFContactID'.

Comment: Can you print all the statement and then run in the diffrent window in SSMS. Commment `EXEC (@V_TABLESCRIPT)` and `EXEC (@V_INSERTSCRIPT)` and uncomment print statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have more `BEGIN` statements (2) than `END` statements (1).  One of them (either the `WHILE` or the `IF`) is not closed so you need to add an `END` to close it.